# How to get reference to route inside action handler?

Tags: ember.js

I have a list of project and ability to delete each of them, here is my action handler for doing this:

```
 deleteProject: function(params) {
   this.store.findRecord('project', params).then(function(project) {
      project.deleteRecord();
      project.save();
      // this.transitionTo('projects');
    });
 }
```

What I want to do is to redirect back to route where list of project is displayed. As you can see I've tried to do this using `this.transitionTo('projects')`, but it doesn't work because `this` does not point to route anymore inside handler.

How to get reference to this `route` where this handler is declared in order to make transition to another route?

I'm using Ember v. 1.13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is a closure:

```
deleteProject: function(params) {
   var self = this;

   this.store.findRecord('project', params).then(function(project) {
      project.deleteRecord();
      project.save();
      self.transitionTo('projects');
   });
}
```

Or you could use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) if you're using ember-cli with transpiler:

```
deleteProject: function(params) {
   this.store.findRecord('project', params).then((project) => {
      project.deleteRecord();
      project.save();
      this.transitionTo('projects');
   });
}
```

Comment: I almost had the same implementation, but it looks like `function expression` changes value of `this` and `arrow function` does not. Can you say few words about this?

Comment: I could say many! But there is so much information about ES6 and arrow functions in the net! :) Long story short, arrow function is lighter in many ways than usual functions (it inherits `this` reference from the parent scope, it doesn't have an `arguments` object, etc). They have nice defaults: you can write `let ids = array.map(item => item.id);` instead of `var ids = array.map(function(item) { return item.id; });` in ES5. I advise you to read something from https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. Hope it works.

```
deleteProject: function(params) {
  var deleteFlag = false;
  this.store.findRecord('project', params).then(function(project) {
    project.deleteRecord();
    project.save();
    deleteFlag = true;
  });

  if (deleteFlag) {
    this.transitionTo('projects');
  } else {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: It won't work because of asynchronous nature of Promises.

Comment: Got it. I think the arrow function is a best choice.